# Check Directory folders in Laravel

Tags: laravel, directory, exists, verify

I know create: makeDirectory(). Also, I know delete, copy, move (deleteDirectory, copyDirectory, moveDirectory). But, how can I verify if the folder exists with laravel. that´s my function

```
public function storeFile(Request $request)
{
    $request->all();
    $folders = $request->file01;
    if($request->hasFile('file01'))
    {
        $request->file01->store('public/'.$folders);
        return "Saved!";
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check it using `is_dir(file_name)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use several methods.

With Laravel you can simply use `File::isDirectory($dir)`. [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_isDirectory)

With PHP you can also just is `is_dir`, [PHP Docs](http://php.net/is_dir)

Answer (score 2):

you can use a php function: [is_dir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php)

`is_dir($path)`